# Django sort by Articles with most similar tags

Tags: python, django

I have a model for Articles and Tags, using filter for suggestions.

The article tags as `tags = article.tags.all()` then filter `Article.objects.filter(tags__in=tags)[:5]` what I'd like is to add a sort by tags similar.

Model for Article and Tags

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag, blank=True, null=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

Comment: Try using tag names and process in loop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use app [django-taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). `TaggableManager` has method `similar_objects` which does exactly what you want.